# Showing/Hiding an image and text using a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a webpage with some styled buttons which show or hide specific content when pressed. Buttons ok, styling ok, show/hide action ok, but I want the content not to be shown by default. So I set the related id's display status as "none". But this time, the content not be shown on the first button click, but on second. How can I make the content not to be shown initially but shown at the very first click?

```js
    function clickFunc1() {
      var x = document.getElementById("id-1");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
      x.style.display = "none"; 
      }
    }
    function clickFunc2() {
     var x = document.getElementById("id-2");
     if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
     } else {
     x.style.display = "none";  
     }
    }
```

```css
 #id-1 {
      display: none;
     }
     #id-2 {
     display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="button-container"> 
      <button class="button-style" onclick="clickFunc1()">Button 1</button>
      <div id="id-1">
       <p>Some text</p>
       <img src="images/some-image-1.jpg" alt="Some image">
      </div>
      <button class="button-style" onclick="clickFunc2()">Button 2</button>
      <div id="id-2">
       <p>Some text</p>
       <img src="images/some-image-2.jpg" alt="Some more image">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `style` property only contains inline styles.

You need to apply `display:none` inline:

```js
function clickFunc1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id-1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function clickFunc2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id-2");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button-style" onclick="clickFunc1()">Button 1</button>
  <div id="id-1" style="display:none">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src="images/some-image-1.jpg" alt="Some image">
  </div>
  <button class="button-style" onclick="clickFunc2()">Button 2</button>
  <div id="id-2" style="display:none">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src="images/some-image-2.jpg" alt="Some more image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the [CSSDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) of the element, and [`getPropertyValue("display")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to get the computed `display` property:

```js
function clickFunc1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id-1");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue("display") === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function clickFunc2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id-2");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue("display") === "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
} else {
  x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

```css
#id-1 {
  display: none;
}

#id-2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="button-style" onclick="clickFunc1()">Button 1</button>
  <div id="id-1" style="display:none">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src="images/some-image-1.jpg" alt="Some image">
  </div>
  <button class="button-style" onclick="clickFunc2()">Button 2</button>
  <div id="id-2" style="display:none">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src="images/some-image-2.jpg" alt="Some more image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot... Would you please explain me the difference between two applications? Thanks again...

Comment: @Alpindos Which applications?

Comment: Oh.. I mean the way I coded "display: none" in css, and your working suggestion making it "inline" in html.

Comment: @Alpindos If you use `window.getComputedStyle` you won't have to set it inline, since it gets the computed style rather than the inline style.

Comment: @Alpindos no problem. If it solves your question, please consider accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions `clickFunc1` and `clickFunc2` are doing exactly the same, except of operating on a different dom element. This would be the perfect use case of a function, that takes a dom element and toggles the display property to the opposite that was predefined (`none` <-> `block`). I've shortended your code for better readability and understanding:

```js
const textOne = document.getElementById('textOne');
const textTwo = document.getElementById('textTwo');

const buttonOne = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById('buttonTwo');

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', () => { toggle(textOne); });
buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', () => { toggle(textTwo); });

function toggle(e) {
  e.style.display = (e.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="buttonOne">Button 1</button>
  <div style="display: none;" id="textOne">
    <p>Some text 1</p>
  </div>
  <button id="buttonTwo">Button 2</button>
  <div style="display: none;" id="textTwo">
    <p>Some text 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That is very useful for me.